# Angular 4 Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: angular

I Get the following error when I try to get a csv from a web api call. When hitting that URL without angular it downloads the csv.

```
Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

**Service**

```
getViolationFile(mid: string, cp: string, d: string, pl: string) {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('mid', mid);
    params.set('cp', cp);
    params.set('d', d);
    params.set('pl', pl);

    let headers = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'text/csv'
    });

    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers,
      search: params,
    });

    return this.http.get('MappViolations/Download?', options);
  }
```

**Component**

```
public submit() {
    this.incomingMappSummaryService.getViolationFile(this.mid, this.cp, this.domain, this.pl)
      .subscribe(data => this.downloadFile(data.body), //gets error here 
      error => console.log('error'),
      () => console.log('success'));
  }



downloadFile(data: Response) {
    let contentType = 'text/csv';
    let blob = new Blob([data.body], { type: contentType }); //this might not be right either but I dont get an error for it
    saveAs(blob, 'data.csv');
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

Comment: what angular version are you using ? Are you injecting HttpClient or Http in the constructor?

Comment: data.json() if you are using angular 5+

Comment: I am using angular 4

Comment: Try data.text()

Comment: return this.http.post(endPointApi, body, options)
      .map((data) => {
        return data.text();
      }).catch(error => { console.log(error)});

Comment: create some app example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @CryingFreeman thank you, that worked.

Comment: @AlexD Can you mark the answer as the one that helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your Service:

```
return this.http.post(endPointApi, body, options)
.map((data) => { return data.text(); })
.catch(error => { console.log(error)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using bracket notation: data['body']

Otherwise double check you're receiving the correct response in JSON format:

data.json()

Answer (score 0):

The type of property data is already Response so no need to use data.body, just :

```
this.downloadFile(data)
```

Comment: when I use this it gets the csv but has "undefined" and no data. If I remove all new Blob([data.body] to just body I get Response with 
'status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:59956/api/MappViolations/Download?&mid=foo&d=foo'